# How can I add a drop down menu dynamically in the Fitnesse?

Tags: fitnesse

I want to embeded a drop down menu in my fitnesse page. The drop down menu should be created at the time of loading of web page. Is there any way we can embeded a HTML tags in fitnesse and create a drop down list.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What is your objective?

Answer (score 1):

Fitness wiki tables get translated into FIT tables. Even if you could add a dropdown (which I do not believe is possible). The converter would not know what to do with it and FIT (or SLIM) would not know how to parse it.

Comment: It would also be worth noting that this would also pose real issues with running in CI or as a part of a suite.   Ultimately FitNesse tests should be deterministic and each test represents a single set of input/output expectations.